# MS Access 2010 Split Database Relationship Problems

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, relationship

I am working on a split database in MS-Access 2010. The back end has relationships between many of the tables. My problem is the front end does not seem to recognise the relationships when I am designing forms, and the relationships do not show up in relationship view. For example, the field 'Service' in tbl_BAYGCharges is a lookup field pointing to the ID of tbl_BAYGServices, so tbl_BAYGServices.ID is related to tbl_BAYGCharges.Service in the back end. When I try to create a form for tbl_BAYGCharges that includes fields from tbl_BAYGServices, the tables do not show as related under 'Add Existing Fields' and a 'Specify Relationship' pop up appears.

I followed the instructions given on the MS website when splitting the tables and have tried re-linking all the tables which had no effect.

I'm relatively new to Access but I am assuming there is a problem here - I want to avoid having to manually create relationships every time I am creating a form and am worried about the future repercussions if the relationships in the back end aren't being recognised.

Comment: I cannot replicate issue. My frontend sees relationships built in backend. This is not a programming issue and question not appropriate for SO.

Comment: I have just re-traced all the steps that got me to where I was and the relationships are being lost in the front end when re-linking the tables after password protecting the back end. Does anybody know a way around this?

Comment: Sorry, I've never used password protection.